# Filling the gaps in the PostgreSQL query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table called `data_users`

```
  id   |    signed_up_at     | product_id
-------+---------------------------------
 20030 | 2017-09-15 12:51:45 | 2
 20122 | 2017-09-15 12:51:45 | 2
 21461 | 2017-09-15 12:51:45 | 2
 20150 | 2017-09-13 10:10:10 | 2
 19858 | 2017-09-10 23:00:54 | 2
 20126 | 2017-09-10 23:00:28 | 2
 20888 | 2017-09-10 23:00:28 | 2
 20143 | 2017-09-10 23:00:28 | 2
 21369 | 2017-09-10 23:00:02 | 2
```

I'm using a query to find a cumulative sum for every day from that table:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', signed_up_at::timestamptz) AS date,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', signed_up_at::timestamptz)) AS sum
FROM "data_users"
WHERE product_id = 2
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Which gives back something like this

```
          date          | sum
------------------------+------
 2017-09-15 00:00:00+02 | 1693
 2017-09-13 00:00:00+02 | 1690
 2017-09-10 00:00:00+02 | 1689
```

As you can see I have gaps in dates for days which don't have users with that `signed_up_at`.

Instead of this, I want to get the following result

```
          date          | sum
------------------------+------
 2017-09-15 00:00:00+02 | 1693
 2017-09-14 00:00:00+02 | 1690
 2017-09-13 00:00:00+02 | 1690
 2017-09-12 00:00:00+02 | 1689
 2017-09-11 00:00:00+02 | 1689
 2017-09-10 00:00:00+02 | 1689
```

So I want to get sum for each day, not just for days that have users with that `signed_up_at`.

I'm trying to achieve that with `GENERATE_SERIES`, but I'm not getting the desired result back:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', signed_up_at::timestamptz) AS date,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', signed_up_at::timestamptz)) AS sum
FROM (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(MIN(signed_up_at)::DATE, MAX(signed_up_at)::DATE, '1 DAY'::INTERVAL) AS date
      FROM "data_users") AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN "data_users" u ON u.signed_up_at::DATE = d.date::DATE
WHERE product_id = 2
GROUP BY signed_up_at ORDER BY date
```

How should I modify my query to support that? Turo's answer helps point me in the right direction, but I have problems with the `WHERE` clause now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no postgress at hand, by i see the problems in the count and the group by, please try

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date::timestamptz) AS date,
       SUM(COUNT(signed_up_at)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', 
date::timestamptz)) AS sum
FROM (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(MIN(signed_up_at)::DATE, MAX(signed_up_at)::DATE, 
'1 DAY'::INTERVAL) AS date
      FROM "data_users") AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN "data_users" u ON u.signed_up_at::DATE = d.date::DATE
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `ERROR:  column "u.signed_up_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Comment: sorry, forgot the signed_up_at in the select(twice)

Comment: I have a where clause that messes this up, I'll edit my question.

Comment: what's the problem with the where clause? my wild guess: where 2 = coalesce(product_id, 2) could help